# How to Load Google API Javascript Client Library into Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

So it's easy to load javascript client library in HTML. I'm talking about this one:

```
https://apis.google.com/js/client.js
```

You just load it using,

```
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">
```

Then you can use it..

```
function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
            'immediate': true
          }, handleAuthResult);
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
          doSomething();
        } else {
          // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
          // clicking authorize button.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
        }
      }
```

**Now, my question:**

How do I do this in Chrome App? How do I load the JS client libraries so I can use it in Chrome app.

Comment: If you are authenticating user try using [Chrome App:Chrome Identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity), as per the documentation: "Web authentication protocols utilize HTTP features, but Chrome Apps run inside the app container; they don’t load over HTTP and can’t perform redirects or set cookies." Here are the list of [JavaScript APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index), Chrome provides apps with many special-purpose APIs like `chrome.runtime` and `chrome.alarms`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way to do this.
Just add the API libraries in your permissions in manifest.json.

```
"permissions": ["https://www.googleapis.com/*"]
```